# jqGrid generating rows but not displaying any data

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, jqgrid-formatter, mvcjqgrid

I am trying to display an ajax data on the jqGrid, although it generates empty rows, no data is displayed.Any help on this would be appreciated. [Click to view copy of my jqGrid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r7GcQ.png) - 
Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<table id="list47"></table>
<div id="plist47"></div>
```

JQuery Code:

```
var mydata=[{ "id": "83123a", Name: "Name 1", "PackageCode": "83123a" },
                { "id": "83432a", Name: "Name 3", "PackageCode": "83432a" },
                { "id": "83566a", Name: "Name 2", "PackageCode": "83566a" }]

var headerData=["id","Name","PackageCode"];

//As header data is taken from another API I would need it in a separate array like the above.

    jQuery("#list47").jqGrid({
        data: mydata,
        datatype: "local",
        height: 150,
        rowNum: 10,
        colNames: headerData,
        colModel: headerData,
        rowList: [10,20,30],
        pager: "#plist47",
        viewrecords: true,
        caption: "json Data grid"
    });
```

I even tried the following, but no progress on this one as well:

```
var md=[{ "id": "83123a", Name: "Name 1", "PackageCode": "83123a" },
                { "id": "83432a", Name: "Name 3", "PackageCode": "83432a" },
                { "id": "83566a", Name: "Name 2", "PackageCode": "83566a" }]

var he=["id","Name","PackageCode"];

jQuery("#list47").jqGrid({
    //data: md,
    datatype: "local",
    height: 150,
    rowNum: 10,
    colNames: he,
    colModel: he,
    rowList: [10,20,30],
    pager: "#plist47",
    viewrecords: true,
     caption: "json data grid"
});
for(var i=0;i<md.length;i++){
 jQuery("#list47").addRowData(i+1,md[i]);
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you! That idea worked for me. I just had to parse my data accordingly into the colModel like this:

```
var md=[{ "id": "83123a", Name: "Name 1", "PackageCode": "83123a" },
                { "id": "83432a", Name: "Name 3", "PackageCode": "83432a" },
                { "id": "83566a", Name: "Name 2", "PackageCode": "83566a" }]

var he=["id","Name","PackageCode"];
var c=[];

for(var i=0;i<he.length;i++){

  c.push('{"name":"'+he[i]+'","index":"'+he[i]+'"}');
}
var colmodel="["+c+"]"

//var colmodel= [{name:'id', index:'id', width:55},
         //     {name:'Name', index:'Name' },
          //      {name:'PackageCode', index:'PackageCode'}]

  // c.push('{"name":"'+he[i]+'","index":"'+he[i]+'"'+'"formatter":'+formatTitle+'}');                  
jQuery("#list47").jqGrid({
    //data: md,
    datatype: "local",
    height: 150,
    rowNum: 10,
    colNames: he,
    colModel: jQuery.parseJSON(colmodel),
    rowList: [10,20,30],
    pager: "#plist47",
    viewrecords: true,
     caption: "json data grid"
});
for(var i=0;i<md.length;i++){
 jQuery("#list47").addRowData(i+1,md[i]);
 }
```

Comment: how you parse the colModel is not an issue in the question hence you should not accept yours as answer.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your colModel is not defined as jqGrid expects it.

[Col Model Options](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:colmodel_options)

As a solution to your problem I added a colmodel variable to hold the correct colmodel definitions and set the colModel grid option to that variable.

Here is a [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/adgptkvj/264/) link to the solution.

```
var md=[{ "id": "83123a", Name: "Name 1", "PackageCode": "83123a" },
                { "id": "83432a", Name: "Name 3", "PackageCode": "83432a" },
                { "id": "83566a", Name: "Name 2", "PackageCode": "83566a" }]

var he=["id","Name","PackageCode"];

var colmodel= [{name:'id', index:'id', width:55},
              {name:'Name', index:'Name' },
                {name:'PackageCode', index:'PackageCode'}]


jQuery("#list47").jqGrid({
    //data: md,
    datatype: "local",
    height: 150,
    rowNum: 10,
    colNames: he,
    colModel: colmodel,
    rowList: [10,20,30],
    pager: "#plist47",
    viewrecords: true,
     caption: "json data grid"
});
for(var i=0;i<md.length;i++){
 jQuery("#list47").addRowData(i+1,md[i]);
 }
```

You can also do and not have the addRowData for loop.

```
jQuery("#list47").jqGrid({
    data: md,
    datatype: "local",
    height: 150,
    rowNum: 10,
    colNames: he,
    colModel: colmodel,
    rowList: [10,20,30],
    pager: "#plist47",
    viewrecords: true,
     caption: "json data grid"
});
```

Comment: +1 for correct pointing the reason of the problem - the value of `colModel`. I still recommend *never fill the grid in the loop by calling `addRowData`. It's the worst way of filling the grid. Instead of that one should just use `data: md` and add `gridview: true` option. See https://jsfiddle.net/adgptkvj/265/

Comment: @Oleg thanks thats why I pointed that at the end of my answer.